# Query about JSON in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have been playing around with JSON a little, but I found something I don't quite understand, for example, I have this piece of code:

```
var str = "{'name':'vvv'}";                    
var cjson = eval ("(" + str + ")");
alert(cjson.name);
```

It works fine, but with this piece of code

```
var str = "{'name':"+'vvv'+"}";    
var cjson = eval ("(" + str + ")");
alert(cjson.name);
```

It does not, I got the following firebug error : ReferenceError: vvv is not defined.

Why doesnt it works with the second way, isnt str a valid string in both cases?

Comment: That's not valid JSON, double quotes are required.

Comment: You need to add quotes around 'vvv', after string concatenation you get var str = "{'name':vvv}"; You should have something like var str = "{'name':"+ "'vvv'" +"}";

Answer (score 3):

It's a string, yes. But not the same string, and not valid JSON.

```
 var str = "{'name':" + 'vvv' + "}";
```

is the same as:

```
 var str = "{'name':" + "vvv" + "}";
```

which is the same as:

```
 var str = "{'name':vvv}";
```

When you try to evaluate that, it's as if you'd declared:

```
 var cjson = { 'name': vvv };
```

and you have no variable named `vvv`.

Comment: For the record, valid JSON would be `var str = '{"name": "vvv"}';`

Answer (score 0):

when you do `var str = "{'name':"+'vvv'+"}";`, the generated string is `"{'name':vvv}"` where `vvv` is not a string literal. So the eval will try to resolve it in the execution scope, since it is not found there it throws an error